# Remove text inside span

Tags: html, css

I want to remove time + icon shown in my blog page

`<span><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>47 sec read</span>`

I have tried using

`.fa-newspaper-o{display:hidden}`

but it only hides the icon before "47 sec" leaves the text displayed

Whole code

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li><span class="posted-in"> <a class="national" href="http://www.fact-file.com/category/national/?customize_changeset_uuid=2a4ce41e-5aad-4e11-bb78-50c7e06dd416&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0" rel="category tag" style="background-color: #1abc9c">National</a>
      <a class="top" href="http://www.fact-file.com/category/top/?customize_changeset_uuid=2a4ce41e-5aad-4e11-bb78-50c7e06dd416&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0" rel="category tag" style="">Top Story</a>
    </span></li>
  <li>
    <span class="right"><a href="#" class="zilla-likes" id="zilla-likes-2010" title="Like this"><span class="zilla-likes-count">0</span> <span class="zilla-likes-postfix"></span></a></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="post-comments-number">
      <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><a href="http://www.fact-file.com/2020/03/22/sindh-govt-decides-to-impose-lockdown-across-the-province/?customize_changeset_uuid=2a4ce41e-5aad-4e11-bb78-50c7e06dd416&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0#respond">0</a> </span>
  </li>
  <li><span><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>47 sec read</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `display:hidden` and you need to hide the `span` element that wraps the icon and the text (Give it some class and use it to hide the whole element)

Answer (score 2):

`.list-inline li:nth-child(4) { display: none;}` or `.list-inline li:last-child { display: none;}` will hide the list item in question.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above, you can use visibility: hidden if you want the removed element to still leave a [footprint (take up space)](https://dev.to/stephencweiss/display-none-vs-visibility-hidden-2pg3).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var li=document.getElementsByTagName('li');
li[li.length-1].style.visibility='hidden';
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li><span class="posted-in"> <a class="national" href="http://www.fact-file.com/category/national/?customize_changeset_uuid=2a4ce41e-5aad-4e11-bb78-50c7e06dd416&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0" rel="category tag" style="background-color: #1abc9c">National</a>
      <a class="top" href="http://www.fact-file.com/category/top/?customize_changeset_uuid=2a4ce41e-5aad-4e11-bb78-50c7e06dd416&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0" rel="category tag" style="">Top Story</a>
    </span></li>
  <li>
    <span class="right"><a href="#" class="zilla-likes" id="zilla-likes-2010" title="Like this"><span class="zilla-likes-count">0</span> <span class="zilla-likes-postfix"></span></a></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="post-comments-number">
      <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><a href="http://www.fact-file.com/2020/03/22/sindh-govt-decides-to-impose-lockdown-across-the-province/?customize_changeset_uuid=2a4ce41e-5aad-4e11-bb78-50c7e06dd416&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0#respond">0</a> </span>
  </li>
  <li><span><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o">47 sec read</i></span></li>
</ul>
```